# Zoo Visitor and Structure - Different Urls and Templates per member group

Tags: structure, zoo-visitor

I'm using Structure and Zoo Visitor for a Recruitment site I'm currently working on which will have two distinct types of users (I have two seperate member groups for permissions).

1. Staff Members (Login access to CP, add/edit/delete Blog Posts, Jobs Postings, etc).
2. Candidates (No Access to CP. Register on Front-end, edit their own profile, Apply for Jobs etc.)

What I'm struggling with is how I'd setup the Urls bearing in mind I use Structure to manage that. How will I be able to distiguish between the two member groups so I can have different Urls / Templates etc?

I've added the Zoo Visitor Member channel to Structure as a listing, but I notice the Structure tab is missing when editing an Entry. Which would make sense as there doesn't look like any way to determine which member group you're dealing with.

Ideally I'd like to have:

```
/team/ (listing of all Staff members).
/team/joe-bloggs (an individual staff member)

/candidate (only display your own profile when logged in)
/candidate/login (speaks for itself).
```

**EDIT**: I can accomplish the `/candidate/` section of the site fine using the standard Zoo Visitor templates. What I can't seem to do is assign a specific template to the the staff member part `/team/joe-bloggs/`. The Structure tab is missing from the Add / Edit Entry form in CP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was just a matter of resetting the publishing layout when editing a Zoo Visitor Member. The Structure tab is now restored and I can assign the desired template to the entry.

Possibly caused by installing Zoo Visitor after Structure? No idea, but it's all working now!

Thanks to the [Zoo guys](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/zoo-visitor/viewthread/8687) for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you wrap the different navigation sets in if member conditionals and show them based on their permissions?

Comment: Hi Travis, could you expand a little as I'm not totally sure what you mean?

Comment: I think I see what you mean with regard to controlling what is displayed on the template itself. What I can't achieve is assigning an actual template to the channel.  The Structure tab itself is missing when I add/edit a Zoo Visitor Entry. So current, when I visit /team/<member name> I get a 404 and a 'Template group and template not found, showing 404 page' message in template debugging. Which is right because I haven't assigned a template yet because I can't.